# jquery ajax calls to wcf rest service for CRUD operations not returning updated values to the frontend

Tags: ajax, wcf, rest, iis

I am Accessing a WCF rest service using Jquery ajax to insert values into database. When i retrieve values in jquery, the changes are not being reflected in the front end, but new values exists in the database. Jquery code is a part of Asp.net MVC application and runs on iis express.

Comment: can you please share the code where you are fetching the new values after update?

Comment: Sounds like a persistence issue... Maybe you are using Entity Framework or a similar ORM with WCF service host InstanceContextMode other than Single (so you have multiple instances of your service). In such a case, your insert may hit ServiceInstanceA which updates its state and writes to the database. Then your query hits ServiceInstanceB which does not know that A has updated the database, so it queries its in-memory state and returns the old value (instead of requery-ing the database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved by turning off cache in my jquery ajax script.

cache: false